# How to prove that for $0 < a \leq 1$ and $a \not = 1/n$ there exists the maximal $k$ s.t $k\cdot a < 1$

Tags: real-numbers

In [this](http://www.pme-math.org/journal/issues/PMEJ.Vol.1.No.1.2.3(reprint).pdf) article of IIME Journal, at page 16, it is claimed that

> for $0 < a \leq 1$ and $a \not = 1/n$ for any integer $n$, there
> exists an integer $k$ such that $k\cdot a < 1$ and $k$ is the greatest integer
> satisfying this condition.

However, how can we show the existence of such a $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: Hint: $a$ lies between some $\frac{1}{k}$ and $\frac{1}{k+1}$.

Comment: @Dzoooks When we are trying to show existence of such a $k$, how can you claim such a thing.

Comment: Note $(0,1] = \sqcup_{k \geq 1} \left(\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{1}{k}\right],$ and $a \in (0,1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $a>0$, there is some positive integer $N$ such that $a>1/N$.  Then for any $m\geq N$, $ma>1$.  So, there are only finitely many positive integers $k$ such that $ka\leq 1$ (and there exists at least one such $k$, namely $k=1$).  Any finite nonempty subset of a totally ordered set has a greatest element, so there is a greatest positive integer $k$ such that $ka\leq 1$.  Finally, we cannot have $ka=1$ for this $k$ since then $a$ would be equal to $1/k$.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

Rephrasing :

$0<a<1$ , since $a= 1 =1/1$ is excluded.

$S:=${$k | k \in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t. $ka <1$}, or

$S= ${$k|k \in \mathbb{Z}$  s.t.  $k<1/a$}.

Note: $S \not = \emptyset$ since $k=1 \in S$.

$S$ is bounded above by $1/a$, $\sup(S)$

exists,  which implies that $S$ has a

maximal element $m \ge 1$..